# Daily Job scheduler using Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz-core

Requirement:

2015-02-11 to 2015-02-15 / 10:30 to 11:30 job to be execute and when 11:30 time comes it should stop the job it should occur util 15th day comes.

Here I have Quartz 1.8.6 lib, but not able to get right implementation for this. Please help us on this.

Sample program:

```
        SimpleDateFormat    formateDate = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/DD/yyyy HH:mm");         
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(AppConstants.QUARTZ_PROP_FILE);
        log.info("------- invoking scheduler ----------------------");

        System.out.println("------- invoking scheduler ----------------------");
        Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();


        java.util.Calendar startCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        startCal.setTime(formateDate.parse(startDate));


        java.util.Calendar endCal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.setTime(formateDate.parse(endDate));


        System.out.println("start/end : " + startCal.getTime() + "/"+endCal.getTime());
        DailyCalendar cal = new DailyCalendar(startTime, endTime);

    //  cal.setTimeRange(startTime, endTime);
        cal.setInvertTimeRange(true);
        Calendar quartzCal = cal;

        sched.addCalendar("quartzCal", quartzCal, true, true);


        //makeDailyTrigger(tgName, 12, 15)
        JobDetail job = new JobDetail(jbName, "Admit", DemandStartJob.class);

        SimpleTrigger trigger=new SimpleTrigger(tgName);
        trigger.setStartTime(startCal.getTime());
        trigger.setEndTime(endCal.getTime());
        trigger.setCalendarName("quartzCal");
        trigger.setJobName(jbName);
        trigger.setJobGroup("Admit");
        trigger.setRepeatCount(0);
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(1);
        sched.scheduleJob(trigger);
        sched.start();
```

Comment: Are you able to make the sample application work? I mean running job in every 1 minute or something?

Comment: Here I am not running 1 min, just I want to run the trigger from 12th to 14th on daily at 10 am to 11 am....

Comment: Basically the logic will be same you have to create a simple trigger code and modify the trigger to run for  12th to 14th on daily at 10 am to 11 am. See the answer I wrote. you can use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to create cron

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you, Can you please explain more

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code to configure Quartz crontrigger

```
// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
.withIdentity("job1", "group1")
.build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
Trigger  trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
.withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 42 10 * * ?"))
.forJob(myJobKey)
.build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Here "**0 42 10 * * ?**" is the cron expression
use http://www.cronmaker.com/
to make a cron expression of your need

If you want to stop the thread also configure another job which triggers after 15 minutes to first job.